# why does kivy show this error when running?

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

***Hello Helpers,***

i installed **kivy** and the dependencies from [kivy.org](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/gettingstarted/installation.html#install-pip) with pip

when i try to run a simple app

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label 


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text="Hello world!!")


if _name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

it shows this error >>

```
ValueError: kivy._event.EventDispatcher size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 40 from C header, got 36 from PyObject
```

any help Please

Comment: New to me. I would try cleaning and reinstalling kivy, on the off chance you have some binary files built against different targets.

Comment: @inclement, i have done that but the same error appears

Comment: @inclement take a loot at the solution below

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

**SOLUTION**

I was using Python **V3.8.3 32bit** i installed  **3.9.2 64bit** and reinstall **kivy** again then it works, that was my solution, i think the issue is in the **32bit** version and **kivy** only runs on **64bit** (i just think so), i hope that helps others.